# How to organize java classes?

Tags: java

I am building a simple POS for my business. I own a little restaurant and would like to make my life easier. I have a class (main menu) that extends JPanel, this class has layout BorderLayout. The menu has a set of panel (NORTH) with button, a JList(WEST), another panel with buttons(CENTER) to change the submenus(EAST), and another buttons(SOUTH) for removing and/or modifying items on list.

When I click on modify (a button on the south panel) another panel should appear. This panel is for the most part the same as the main menu. It has a menu on the north, a list on the west, etc. The part that differs is the actions the buttons on the north and the buttons on the south perform.

My question is:

- 1) should I create a general class and extend to create this two menus I need
- 2) should I add an inner class to each extended class for the corresponding functionality of the buttons or should I create external actions.

I am always confused about how to treat events. Create external classes and pass listeners to classes or to use nested classes (but sometimes I find too many nested classes).

If you need me to post the code let me know. Is a little long, this is why I did not post it!

Comment: I would say: don't reinvent the wheel: http://blog.capterra.com/the-top-6-free-and-open-source-pos-solutions/

Comment: Use a GUI builder, as comes for instance with NetBeans IDE. Do not start to overuse inheritance; can be done later. Maybe look into Model-View-Controller architecture. Inner classes better for Listeners. Access to other JComponents better via a controller class. Main class could be such a controller holding the JFrame.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I certainly appreciate your suggestion. However, I think your are missing half of the goal. Yes, I do need a POS, but I also want to learn. So, if you have a comment or suggestion with regards to my questions I will greatly appreciate it!

Comment: For learning too, start with a maven project: maven provides a build infrastructure, like managing versioned libraries, and providing conventions like folder hierarchies. Then try TDD, test driven developments. First datastructures (the Model) with test cases doing the buisiness logic. Then realize it in a GUI.

Comment: @Joop Eggen Do I need to install anything?

Comment: @Gacci I don't know about the regulations that exist in the US, but in Europe several countries will accuse you of tax fraud when you use a non-certified POS application. But I assume the US will be more liberal

Comment: No, the maven build tool is available in all general IDEs; in eclipse you  need a plugin. For TDD you can make JUnit tests for every use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Much of this is opinion based, but here goes anyway...

I would suggest creating subclasses for the different menus, each extending a abstract class defining the common elements. Have them in the same package.

As for event handlers, that's trickier. Sometimes an even handler is only used in one place, in that case, an anonymous inner class (or lambda in Java 8) is the best approach. But if the same handler may be used for different events, then remember the [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle, and use a separate class.